# Symmetric matrices of indeterminates and an irreducible polynomial

Tags: matrices, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Let $W =[w_{ij}] $ be a symmetric matrix of indeterminates. I wonder if the polynomial $p(W) := \mathrm{tr}(W^3)-r_0$, $r_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is irreducible over reals.

Comment: Any irreducible *real* polynomial has degree one or two.

Comment: @DonAntonio It works only for univariate polynomials which is not necessarily the case in this question.

Comment: @user26857 Good point, indeed.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hence, the zero locus of p(W) has many connected components?

Comment: If $W$ 2x2, and $r_0=0$, then $p(W)$ is divisible by $tr(W)$. But for $r_0\neq0$ it is irreducible as it is a pure quadratic in $w_{12}$ with coprime quadratic and constant coefficients. Don't know about 3x3 or higher.